# SQL Server Reporting Services does not start

Tags: sql-server-2014

> Error 1053
>   The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

I was trying to start SQL Server Reporting Service (on SQL Server Express) from `service.msc`.

Please help me start the SQL Server Reporting Service.

Comment: Check the logs and tell us what they say.

Comment: Also, I *assume* you installed SQL Server Express with Advanced Services.

Comment: @Larnu Report Server Windows Service (anotherinstancename) cannot connect to the report server database.

Comment: And is the data engine that SSRS needs to connect to running..? Have you configured the details for the data engine in SSRS correctly?

Comment: SQL Server(express) working

Comment: @Larnu it was working fine but suddenly stopped

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL Server Developer (64-bit)Version 14.0.2027.2 on Win 10 Pro

Re-installed **SQLServerReportingServices.exe** (download from Microsoft) and finally working again.  Had to delete pre-existing installation fold to prevent re-install error.